# JQuery Upload 8.8.5 : Delete issue on Live Server Linux

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I'm working to solve a big "issue". I used the JQuery Up code to upload images in my website. Everything works well on my WAMP server, but once i work on the Live Server, only the "delete" action doesn't work. You can figure out by yourself : www.palmeraiecards.com/ecardma/

I don't think it's a problem with the code or the "webserver rights" because CHMOD is put to 777 for users.

What about this mess ?

```
 {% if (file.deleteUrl) { %}
            <button class="btn btn-danger delete" data-type="{%=file.deleteType%}" data-url="{%=file.deleteUrl%}">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                <span>Delete</span>
            </button>




        {% } else { %}
            <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                <span>Cancel</span>
            </button>
        {% } %}
```

Thank you :)

Comment: your wamp install might not have the proper permissions, you should probably ask this over at [the unix stackexchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I understand, but it's a live server. Do I need to ask the Webserver Admin ? But when i use the function unlink(), it runs !

Comment: OK ! Problem solved ! We found an incompatibilyt with our server so we've modify : 'delete_type' => 'DELETE', to 'delete_type' => 'POST', (in UploadHandler.js file line:47). It works now !Thank u